# wordpress version 5.6 hides the left column of the backend admin interface on post/page editing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

After opening a post or page for editing, wordpress hides the left column of the admin backend interface. Is there a way to disable this behaviour and return to the left column always visible?

This is what I have:
[image]

This is what I miss:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gutenberg displays in fullscreen mode by default.

When editing your post (in your screenshot the "hello world"), click the three dots in right top corner. In the menu, click on the "Fullscreen mode" item to deactivate fullscreen mode of gutenberg.